# GLSurfaceView onResume - Tabbed Apllication create Context

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsurfaceview

I have a tabbed-application which uses an `GLSurfaceView`. If I tab the first time, the view is beeing created and shown. If I tab it twice, the surface is beeing destoryed, but not new created. The methods `onStop()` and `onResume()` are called. If I press teh home-button, the surface is beeing destroyed. When I open the app again, a new surface is beeing created.

My question is now: Why does no the `eglContext` is beeing created, when I want to show the view a second time? Why is no new `GLThread` created? Or how can I force a recreation of the `EGLSurface` and `GLThread`? On my Samsung  Galaxy mini it doesnt work. On my Samsung Galaxy SII it works. I googled the problem and found a bug in the `GLSurfaceView`, but no working fix.

Thanks for some useful answers and excuse me for my english :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you got the `IllegalArgumentException`?

```
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): eglCreateWindowSurface
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Make sure the SurfaceView or associated SurfaceHolder has a valid Surface
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl._eglCreateWindowSurface(Native Method)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at com.google.android.gles_jni.EGLImpl.eglCreateWindowSurface(EGLImpl.java:90)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$DefaultWindowSurfaceFactory.createWindowSurface(GLSurfaceView.java:798)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.createSurface(GLSurfaceView.java:1065)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1433)
10-08 18:05:36.490: E/GLSurfaceView(3440): at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1216)
```

If yes, you should patch your `GLSurfaceView`.

from:

```
                if (createEglSurface) {
                    if (LOG_SURFACE) {
                        Log.w("GLThread", "egl createSurface");
                    }
                    gl = (GL10) mEglHelper.createSurface(getHolder());
                    if (gl == null) {
                        // Couldn't create a surface. Quit quietly.
                        break;
                    }
                    sGLThreadManager.checkGLDriver(gl);
                    createEglSurface = false;
                }
```

to:

```
                if (createEglSurface) {
                    if (LOG_SURFACE) {
                        Log.w("GLThread", "egl createSurface");
                    }
                    gl = (GL10) mEglHelper.createSurface(getHolder());
                    if (gl == null) {
                        // If we escape, GLThread ends up. Don't escape.
                        continue;
                    }
                    sGLThreadManager.checkGLDriver(gl);
                    createEglSurface = false;
                }
```

I create my [GLSurfaceView class](https://gist.github.com/3890965) and patch it like above.

It was fixed in JellyBean. see also this [commit](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/7d73df83f9a28950f404e957eb2e4ea1e8525c55).